# Taking a Picture With Camera and Viewing in Image View

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I don't know why my code which was just working and has suddenly stopped? I want to take a picture through my image button, and then display it in an Image View. Here`s my code that won't display in the Image View:

```
public class UserInterface extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE= 1;
    private ImageView imageView;
    ImageButton cap;
    Bundle extras;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_interface);
        imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        cap = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.cap);
        cap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             extras = data.getExtras();
             imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks good to me. Is there an error? Or the camera opens up but the captured image is not getting to the image view? Or nothing happens at all?

Comment: The captured image isn't going to the image view. The camera comes up, and it saves the image on my phone but it doesn't come up in the image view.

Comment: Are you sure the imageView id is imageView1 ?

Comment: Yup I just checked that.

Comment: Is the onActivityResult() method getting called? Put some log messages and check that.

Comment: Try setting a a default image for your image view at first . I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the visibility of your image view . I have just run your code it is working fine . If possible please post your code for  activity_user_interface.xml file

Comment: Alright I'll try setting a default image tommorow. Just been out lately I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri imageUri;
```

On your button click listener:

```
cap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
});
```

On activity result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```